# connect to secure ADLS (where public network access is disabled) storage container from Fabric workspace pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-storage, microsoft-fabric

is there an easy way to connect to secure ADLS (where public network access is disabled) storage container from Fabric workspace pipelines? if the storage account is public, we can connect but I need a way to copy data from secured ADSLS gen2 storage account to onelake in fabric using ADF.

Comment: The normal way to do it would be by VNet and using private endpoints to connect anywhere from there, but its currently not supported for Fabric. When you turn on Block Internet Access, Microsoft Fabric is disabled.

Comment: However, you can put all your assets into a VNet, including your fabric. And you can use managed VNet for ADF. This I think should be supported. The only downside is not only your ADLS will be limited to network access from outside, but all your assets, you can specify IP ranges in the firewall settings that are allowed.

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas Thanks for the response. Are you referring something like this ..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAo_J6UFB9Y&t=710s . Bur it seems to me too complicated. Ideally Fabric should allow a shortcut eventually. But in case do you know of any easy tutorial link can you please share?

Comment: I have watched the video, since Fabric is a new product, I dont know what exact route to take here, but you can try something similar in the video, but the problem is your ADLS is not on-prem as the sql server in the video. Your ADLS is on the cloud. You should be able to provision your assets inside the VNet, as long as there is no private endpoint involved against the fabric itself, its good to try out. You can have your ADF managed VNet outside your original VNet like the video if you want, or you can just include it in the VNet as well.

Comment: @ZiyaMertKarakas when you suggested --"However, you can put all your assets into a VNet, including your fabric." is it possible to assign vnet to the Fabric which is SAAS?

Comment: Honest with you, I never tried a network solution yet with Fabric, as its new. I am sure there is a way, but there arent enough resources on the web to suggest an alternative approach to private endpoint or VNet. I think maybe the networking team at Azure would have an answer to this, maybe you can create a ticket with team, with the VNet team specifically (Private endpoint should have another team). I can also do some testing with private ADLS on my environment, but that will take some time. Maybe you can try the setup in the video, and manually do the IP ranges